# Login and Redirect to his Page

Tags: php

I created a login page. Based on the username and password it should redirect the user to their home page.

My pages are `login.php`, `class1.php`, `class2.php`.

If a user logs in based on their username and password he is redirected to either `class1` or `class2`.

I don't know how to connect the login page with the PHP server.

I have tried it in JS but its simple and can be seen by anyone.

Comment: Please attach the code you tried.

Comment: @AllenChak Judging from the question he has no PHP and is therefore asking for the whole server-side login code.

Comment: That s What i mentioned Stanyer

Answer (score 2):

if you are base on the username and password. if username and password are match in database then after redirect page in profile page or any main page.

```
<?php

  if($passwordmatch)
    {
       header('location: userprofile.php')
    }
   else
   {
        $error_msg="Username and password is not match";
        return  $error_msg;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
header("Location: class1.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you've got a simple HTML form with username and password field, using `POST` method.

Then you submit this form with a submit button and read the values in PHP with `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`.

Then you check the values against the values saved in the database.

When you get a result of the combined values, then you can redirect the user using

> header("Location: yourfile.php");

I think this is enough for an idea how it could work, because this is not the platform for "Write the code for me, please".

Answer (score 0):

This one shoudl do the trick. If the user logs i successful, he will be redirected to your class.

```
if(login_successful) {
    header("Location: class1.php");
}
```

Optionally, you can use JavaScript with location.href.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add your code so it's hard to help but you should try doing something similar to this:

```
if ($loginOk)
    echo"<script>location.href='your_url/class1.php'</script>";
else
    echo"<script>location.href='your_url/class2.php'</script>";
```

You can also use `header("Location: class1.php")` as suggested but make sure you don't send any text to the browser before this line, otherwise, it won't work because the headers were already sent and you'll probably get this warning:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (output started at file:line)
```